# how to display a variable that contain html template in smarty?

Tags: variables, smarty, template-engine

how to display a variable that contain html template in smarty?

```
$smarty = new my_smarty();
$page_content = "<p>{$my_content}</p>";
$smary->assign("my_content","whatever...");

$smarty->display($page_content); // how to render $page_content ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl):

> Smarty can render templates from a string by using the `string:` or `eval:` resource.
>
> The `string:` resource behaves much the same as a template file. The template source is compiled from a string and stores the compiled template code for later reuse. [...]
>
> The `eval:` resource evaluates the template source every time a page is rendered. [...]

For your case:

```
$smarty = new my_smarty();
$page_content = "<p>{$my_content}</p>";
$smary->assign("my_content","whatever...");

$smarty->display("string:" . $page_content);
```